# How to turn a string representation of a javascript object into an actual object?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to programatically create a javascript object (to be handed off to an AJAX Handler) by programatically concatenating strings.

However (and this is very simplified):

```
var data = "{ field1: 'Val1', field2: 'Val2' }";
```

Is not the same thing at all as:

```
var data = { field1: 'Val1', field2: 'Val2' };
```

Is there a way to convert that string representation of an object into an actual object?

**EDIT**: For clarification of why I am asking this, field1, and field 2 are programatically added to the string inside of a loop.  Otherwise, I would just construct the object the normal way.

Comment: Even if the name of `field1` is dynamic you can directly construct your object. I currently do not see the point of creating a string and then trying to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on your string.

As a result will be:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"field1": "Val1", "field2": "Val2" }');
```

Comment: I'm familiar with JSON.parse(), so I think I can fix that.  thanks.  What's missing?

Comment: You need to use double quotes in keys and values of your object.

Comment: Yes, I;ve done that too.  I think I know how to fix it and proceed.  If works, will mark this as answer.  Thanks.

Comment: w3schools article on [json.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) might help

Answer (score 1):

You could use `eval` to parse the string, or `new Function` The parenthesis are important for eval as you need to evaluate the object as an object expression.

```js
var data = "{ field1: 'Val1', field2: 'Val2' }";

const evil = x => {
  "use strict"
  return eval(x)
}

console.log(evil(`(${data})`))

console.log(new Function(`return ${data}`)())
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please don't use `eval`. If at all possible, give preference to `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

your data has to be

```
var data = '{"field1": "Val1", "field2":"Val2"}';
```

then, you can use the standard JS method JSON.Parse() like below:

```
var ObjectData = JSON.Parse(data);
```

so the end result will be:

```
ObjectData = {field1: "Val1", field2: "Val2"};
```

you can use this tool - https://jsonlint.com/ to verify if you JSON data is valid or not

Answer (score 0):

The syntax used below will not bring up any errors, and the result will be object.

```js
var o = JSON.parse("{ \"field1\": \"Val1\", \"field2\": \"Val2\" }");
console.log(typeof(o));
var o2 = JSON.parse('{ "field1": "Val1", "field2": "Val2" }');
console.log(typeof(o2));
var o3 = JSON.parse('{ \"field1\": \"Val1\", \"field2\": \"Val2\" }');
console.log(typeof(o3));
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1. Using JSON

If you just need to transmit some objects between client and server, consider using **JSON**

> In computing, JavaScript Object Notation or JSON (/ˈdʒeɪsən/ JAY-sən) is an open-standard file format that uses human-readable text to transmit data objects <…>. It is a very common data format used for asynchronous browser–server communication <…>.
>   - Wikipedia

As there is either a built-in support or a library implementation for JSON in many programming languages, including javascript, PHP, Java and many others, this will help you avoid some overhead of manual string concatenation and parsing.

So, on the server you are going to do something like:

```
let result = JSON.stringify({foo: "foo", bar: "bar"});
```

This is a javascript example, but you could do it nearly the same way in PHP or Java, or almost any other language.

Encoding the above object will result in the following output string:

```
'{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar"}'
```

The string can be sent over to the browser using AJAX. Then, in the browser you just:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(dataFromAjax);
```

And get a genuine javascript object. JSON supports objects, numbers, strings, arrays, booleans and null. Note that JSON.parse will throw an error if an invalid JSON string is passed in.

#### Solution 2. Using `eval(str)`

The built-in `eval` function evaluates a javascript expression string and returns the result.

Some examples:

```
let foo = eval("1+1"); // 2 (a number)
let bar = eval('{foo: "foo"}'); // {foo: "foo"} (an object).
```

The first approach is definitely more clean and is preferred, use it if you can.